# Query Update For MAX ID and LNUM

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 1 table for Update MAX(TID) and TEDATE = TSDATE - 1

```
Table1
--------------------------------------------
TID | TSDATE     | TEDATE     | TLNUM | TLOC
--------------------------------------------
247 | 3-JAN-2022 | 2-JAN-2027 | 111   | LOC1
248 | 5-JAN-2022 | 4-JAN-2027 | 112   | LOC2
249 | 3-JAN-2022 | 2-JAN-2027 | 113   | LOC3
250 | 3-JAN-2022 | 2-JAN-2027 | 114   | LOC4
251 | 7-JAN-2022 | 6-JAN-2027 | 115   | LOC5
```

i want update TEDATE for MAX TID(251),LNUM(115) the results for this

```
Table1
--------------------------------------------
TID | TSDATE     | TEDATE     | TLNUM | TLOC
--------------------------------------------
247 | 3-JAN-2022 | 2-JAN-2027 | 111   | LOC1
248 | 5-JAN-2022 | 4-JAN-2027 | 112   | LOC2
249 | 3-JAN-2022 | 2-JAN-2027 | 113   | LOC3
250 | 3-JAN-2022 | 2-JAN-2027 | 114   | LOC4
251 | 7-JAN-2022 | 6-JAN-2022 | 115   | LOC5
```

Comment: Update it to what value? You do not appear to have changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `MAX(TID)`? There's only **one** row.

Did you mean something like this?

```
update table1 a set
  a.tedate = a.tsdate - 1
  where a.tid = (select max(b.tid)
                 from table1 b
                );
```

Comment: Thanks For respon, Littlefoot
Sorry for update max(TID) many rows.
I have edited my question

Comment: Well, 249 is **not** MAX(TID) in data you posted; it is **251**. Is it not?

Comment: Yes 251..
sorry :(

Comment: OK; then query I posted should work.